# Creating multiple dictionary variables with loop commands?

Tags: python, dictionary, xlrd

This is my first time working with python. I'm trying to create a dictionary for each county (23 in total) with year as the key for population and income values.  Strong arming the code seems to work, but I'm sure there is an easier way to do it using loops or classes...any suggestions??  Thanks!!!!!

```
import xlrd

wb= xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Python27\Forecast_test.xls')

popdata=wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet1')
incomedata=wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet2')

WyomingCnty =('Albany', 'Big Horn',
        'Campbell', 'Carbon', 'Converse',
        'Crook', 'Fremont', 'Goshen',
        'Hot Springs','Johnson', 'Laramie',
        'Lincoln', 'Natrona','Niobrara',
        'Park', 'Platte', 'Sheridan', 'Sublette',
        'Sweetwater', 'Teton', 'Uinta', 'Washakie', 'Weston','Wyoming')

Years = ('y0','y1','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6','y7','y8','y9','y10',
    'y11','y12', 'y13', 'y14', 'y15', 'y16', 'y17', 'y18','y19',
    'y20','y21','y22','y23','y24','y25','y26','y27','y28','y29','y30')

AlbanyPop = popdata.col_values(colx=1,start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None)
AlbanyIncome= incomedata.col_values(colx=1,start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None)
AlbanyDict1=dict(zip(Years,AlbanyPop))
AlbanyDict2=dict(zip(Years,AlbanyIncome))

BigHornPop = popdata.col_values(colx=2,start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None)
BigHornIncome= incomedata.col_values(colx=2,start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None)
BigHornDict1=dict(zip(Years,BigHornPop))
BigHornDict2=dict(zip(Years,BigHornIncome))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
popdict = {}
incdict = {}
for ix, city in enumerate(WyomingCnty):
  popdict[city] = dict(zip(Years, popdata.col_values(colx=ix + 1,start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None)
  incdict[city] = dict(zip(Years, incomedata.col_values(colx=ix + 1,start_rowx=1,end_rowx=None)
```

Comment: yeah, the key to this is the `enumerate` built-in function, which is a very handy way of getting numeric index values as you iterate over something.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use another dictionary. As in:

```
import xlrd
wb= xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Python27\Forecast_test.xls')

popdata=wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet1')  #Import population data
incomedata=wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet2') #Import income data

WyomingCnty =('Albany', 'Big Horn',
            'Campbell', 'Carbon', 'Converse',
            'Crook', 'Fremont', 'Goshen',
            'Hot Springs','Johnson', 'Laramie',
            'Lincoln', 'Natrona','Niobrara',
            'Park', 'Platte', 'Sheridan', 'Sublette',
            'Sweetwater', 'Teton', 'Uinta', 'Washakie', 'Weston','Wyoming')

Years = ('y0','y1','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6','y7','y8','y9','y10',
        'y11','y12', 'y13', 'y14', 'y15', 'y16', 'y17', 'y18','y19',
        'y20','y21','y22','y23','y24','y25','y26','y27','y28','y29','y30')

county_dict = {}
for col, county in enumerate(WyomingCnty):
    county_dict[county] = {}
    county_popdata = popdata.col_values(colx=col, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=None)
    county_incdata = incomedata.col_values(colx=col, start_rowx=1, endrowx=None)
    county_dict[county]['population'] = county_popdata
    county_dict[county]['income'] = county_incdata
    county_dict[county]['pop_by_year'] = dict(zip(Years, county_popdata)) 
    county_dict[county]['inc_by_year'] = dict(zip(Years, county_incdata))
```